# Like Query does not returing expected result

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am using Rails 4.2 in our project and using postgresql for Database.

I am not getting proper result when I am apllying 'Like' query. Please read full description below.

```
Campaign.where('lower (brand_name) LIKE ?', "%#{params[:brand_name]}%")
```

now what is the problem with this query, suppose I have created record with `brand_name("brand-10%")` and then I am searching record by passing parameter `like "10%"` in brand_name column then this query not returning exact record. it is returning all records those have "10" as brand_name.

I have checked the query and it is making SQL query like:

```
SELECT "campaigns".* FROM "campaigns" WHERE (lower (brand_name) LIKE '%10%%')
```

but now what I want that like query should be apply on "10%" instead of "10".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because `%` is the wildcard character and matches 0 or more characters.  So having `%%` at the end of the string `'%10%%'` is no different to just `'%10%'`.

You will need to escape the first `%` to make it match a literal percent sign.  According to the postgresql manual you need to prefix this with the escape character defaulted to `\`. Unfortunetly `\` is ruby's escape character so you will need to use `\\` to mean `\`.

> To match a literal underscore or percent sign without matching other
>   characters, the respective character in pattern must be preceded by
>   the escape character. The default escape character is the backslash
>   but a different one can be selected by using the ESCAPE clause. To
>   match the escape character itself, write two escape characters.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html

I'm not fluent with ruby-on-rails just with postgresql.    Entirely off the top of my head this will look like:

```
Campaign.where("lower (brand_name) LIKE '%' || replace(?, '%', '\\%') || '%'", "#{params[:brand_name]}")
```

Comment: you mean I have to write query:

Campaign.where("LOWER(brand_name) LIKE ?", "\%#{params[:brand_name]} %")

Comment: No. I mean you need to replace every `%` in `brand_name` with `\%`.  So your query will be `SELECT "campaigns".* FROM "campaigns" WHERE (lower (brand_name) LIKE '%10\%%')`

Comment: I checked and it is still returning same result while I have only one record corrsepond to "10%" brand name. Please check query below.


2.1.5 :067 > Campaign.where("LOWER(brand_name) LIKE ?", "%10%").count
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "campaigns" WHERE (LOWER(brand_name) LIKE '%10%')
 => 65 


2.1.5 :068 > Campaign.where("LOWER(brand_name) LIKE ?", "%10\%%").count
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "campaigns" WHERE (LOWER(brand_name) LIKE '%10%%')
 => 65

Comment: both query returning 65 records.

while I have one record with "10%" brand name and 64 records with "10" brand name